# Execute AsyncTask on Arraylist in Android to Update database

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-asynctask

I have an ArrayList of strings that contains up to 100,000 strings and want to make an HTTP Request to get the data for each string then create and insert it into the database. I'm doing this with the following code right now but it takes way too long and I'm not sure the tasks are executed asynchronously. Is there some way to make this quicker?

```
    ArrayList<String> objects = new ArrayList<String>(); 
AsyncTask<List<String>, Void, Thread> downloadBookTask = new AsyncTask<List<String>, Void, Thread>() {
        @Override
        protected Thread doInBackground(List<String>... params) {

            for (String object : params[0]) {

                HttpURLConnection conn = null;
                try {
                    conn = NetworkManager.getHttpURLConnection(new URL(object));

                    conn.setConnectTimeout(10000);
                    conn.connect();

                    ByteArrayOutputStream bais = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    InputStream is = null;
                    try {
                        is = conn.getInputStream();
                        // Read 4K at a time
                        byte[] byteChunk = new byte[4096];
                        int n;

                        while ((n = is.read(byteChunk)) > 0) {
                            bais.write(byteChunk, 0, n);
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        //e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        if (is != null) {
                            is.close();
                        }
                        conn.disconnect();
                    }
                    saveDownloadedData(object, bais.toByteArray());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }                }
            return null;
        }
    };
    downloadBookTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, objects);
}

public void saveDownloadedData(String object, byte[] data) {
    Book currentBook = new Book(object, data);
    addBookToDatabase(currentBook);       
}
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems like you are executing one asynctask for the list of Strings? Wouldn't you want to start an asynctask for each string in the list?

Comment: I used to have a for loop iterating through the arraylist and inside the for loop I created an asynctask for the current string but it was even slower than it is now

Comment: use Executors for very long tasks, for example ExecutorService newFixedThreadPool (int nThreads) you cand pass the int 3, for 3 threads and execute 3 tasks at the same time, when one task is completed send other task to the executor, after all your tasks are sended to the executor, run executor.shutdown, this will make executor not accepting new tasks, but will finish running current ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It slow because your `downloadBookTask` excute `100,000` http connections `synchronized`.

To improve this code you can try this way: each 1000 strings mean 1000 http connections, you can create an `AsyncTask` to run it `async`.So you will have 100 `AsyncTask` run concurrency, it will be 100 times faster than your way.

Number of `AsyncTask` depend on your device hardware RAM and CPU, you can increase of decrease it to fit your case.

Note: be caful when you use `ArrayList` with `MultiThreading`, it is not `threadsafe`.

Comment: Thank u for your suggestions. I ended up doing it this way and it is much faster now!

Answer (score 0):

You cant improve a lot with your current `HttpRequest`. Looking at your code, you just use 1 `AsyncTask` to do `100,000` requests. Each request need at least `1s` for connection, so It will be 100,000s (too long). There'are some way 2 improve your performance:

1. Spawning 100,000 threads. Ugly right? Dont do that, it will destroy your application.

2. Using 100,000 `AsyncTask`s, not a good idea too (normal `execute` function, all your `AsyncTask` will run on a single thread, you can change that behavior with `executeOnExecutor`, but still awful). 

3. Change your `HttpRequest` to send `100,000` `String` at once and `return` list of objects you need with `json`.

 I think method 3 is the best way to improve your performance, otherwise, AFAIK, there's no way :)

Comment: Changing the HttpRequest would definitely be the best solution but unfortunately in my case that's not an option. Thank u for your suggestions though.